# Unable to execute HTTP request,No address associated with hostname

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify

AuthException(message: Sign in failed, recoverySuggestion: See attached exception for more details., underlyingException: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unable to resolve host "cognito-idp.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname

Answer (score 1):

add internet permission in your `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your app has permission `android.permission.INTERNET` in your app/src/main and debug folders.
and make sure the device has a network connection, either cellular data or Wif

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I was getting this because of a very silly issue. My Mobile data(internet) was off in the phone in which I was debugging/testing the app which was causing this exception. Switching on the mobile data worked.